# Sqlite: Execute Spatialite Functions in Qt5.4.2 or vs2010 along with Qt-addin

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

Does anyone know whether it is possible to execute spatialite functions on sqlite-databases in Qt5 **or visual studio 2010 along with Qt-addin**?

In particular, I would be interested in using functions on type Point.

Thanks!

PS: Functions do work within the official spatialite-gui, however I don't think there is a way to use the spatialite-gui programmatically, is there?

Here is what I tried so far: In Qt5.4.2 I connected SQLITE spatialite database and tried using function ST_X(point), ST_Y(point), ST_PointN and ST_NumPoints with no success:

```
SELECT ST_X(ST_PointN(Geometry, 1)) AS StartX, ST_Y(ST_PointN(Geometry, 1)) AS StartY, ST_X(ST_PointN(Geometry, ST_NumPoints(Geometry))) AS EndX, ST_Y(ST_PointN(Geometry, ST_NumPoints(Geometry))) AS EndY FROM "国道"
```

Then this always cannot be excuted successfully. And I also find some relate solution about java in [Sqlite: Execute Spatialite Functions in Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612745/sqlite-execute-spatialite-functions-in-intellij) but these yet cannot solve my problem:

step 1: download mod_spatialite-4.3.0a-win-x86.7z file from spatialite website and uncompress it into c:\sqlite3
PS: In Window 10, I open sqlite3 by cmd, SQL sentence that `SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')` could be excuted successfully.

step 2: In my Qt's code, add `SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')` before  SQL statement contained spatialite function. Unfortunately, return value by excute `QSqlQuery.exec("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')")` is false. Oh no, this is a depressing message.

What's more, I also find some relate solution about Qt in https://forum.qt.io/topic/69835/why-can-t-qt-be-installed-with-sqlite-that-has-load_extension-enabled. However, This need recompile Qt from source and it beyond my skill. Finally, How do I in Qt5.4.2 **or visual studio 2010 along with Qt-addin**? Has anybody done this before?

Comment: Are you using QSqlQuery in a model (like QSqlQueryModel) OR you are using QSqlQuery just to access data in the database and then you put data in variables and list ?  Because if it's the second case you could simply forget about QSqlQuery and use directly the sqllite library.

Comment: @Marco Thanks for your comment. And I have some problem about your above comment: Has other method to access sqlite database except for QSqlQuery? And what QSqlQuery means? And what relationship about QSqlQuery and spatialite function?

Comment: QSqlQuery is a c++/Qt class that you are using to get data from the sqlite database, but Qt is also c++ so you are free to use any c++ sqlite library to open you sqlite database. https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Comment: And if you add some more code to your post it's going to be much easier helping you

Comment: @Marco Thanks again. You give me a great remind. You are right! I can write a c++ program to connect sqlite database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help very much, particularly, @Marco and @CL..

Below is my two solution:

PS:
First of all, download mod_spatialite-4.3.0a-win-x86.7z from http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86/. Then, copy file named mod_spatialite.dll to your project's execute content(equal to your .exe program files). Next, write your Qt project and run this Qt project to test it.

My machine runtime: **Window 10 + Qt5.4.2 + Sqlite3**

**First Solution:**

As @CL. says,

> If you are not able to call the SQLite library functions directly from your Qt application, then your only choice is to recompile Qt (or the Qt plugin).

So I recompile sqlite Qt plugin (file path is C:\Qt\Qt5.4.2\5.4\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers). Then modify two position:

1. add `DEFINES -= SQLITE_OMIT_LOAD_EXTENSION` in sqlite.pro;
2. add below code block in function named open of qsql_sqlite.cpp:

   ```
   if (sqlite3_open_v2(db.toUtf8().constData(), &d->access, openMode, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    ...

    char* zErrMsg = 0;
    char* spatialiteDll = "mod_spatialite";
    sqlite3_enable_load_extension(d->access, 1);
    sqlite3_load_extension(d->access, spatialiteDll, 0, &zErrMsg);

    ...
   ```

   }

**Second Solution: Reference links: https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html**

As @Marco says,

> QSqlQuery is a c++/Qt class that you are using to get data from the sqlite database, but Qt is also c++ so you are free to use any c++ sqlite library to open you sqlite database. sqlite.org/quickstart.html

So, I get below code to execute SQL sentence along with spatialite function in Qt5.

Example Code:

```
  #include <QCoreApplication>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <sqlite3.h>

  static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++){
      printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv){
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    sqlite3 *db;
    char *zErrMsg = 0;
    int rc;

    if( argc!=3 ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT\n", argv[0]);
      return(1);
    }
    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db);
    if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      sqlite3_close(db);
      return(1);
    }

    char* spatialiteDll = "mod_spatialite";
    sqlite3_enable_load_extension(db, 1);
    sqlite3_load_extension(db, spatialiteDll, 0, &zErrMsg);
    fprintf(stderr, "sqlite3 error: %s\n", zErrMsg);

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
    if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
      fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
      sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return a.exec();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [load_extension() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension) says:

> For security reasons, extension loaded is turned off by default.

You have to enable it with the C function [sqlite3_enable_load_extension()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/enable_load_extension.html) or [sqlite3_db_config](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/db_config.html)(…[SQLITE_DBCONFIG_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_dbconfig_enable_fkey.html)…).
And when you're calling C functions anyway, you can also use [sqlite3_load_extension()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/load_extension.html).

If you are not able to call the SQLite library functions directly from your Qt application, then your only choice is to recompile Qt (or the Qt plugin).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And I still have some problem: According to your answer, Do I must download source code of Qt5.4.2 then recompile it? So as you say, how do I configure and use sqlite3_load_extension() in Qt5.4.2 or my qt project?

Comment: Thanks again. You are right. I am sure to need rewrite sqlite driver plugin for Qt. Now, I doing it.